# MySQL trigger after insert delete query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

I have the following trigger, created in phpMyAdmin:

`Table: tb_agenda
 Time: AFTER
 Event: INSERT`

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_agenda INTO x;

    SET i = 0;

    WHILE i < x DO
        INSERT INTO tb_realizacao (dt_agenda,
                                   titulo, 
                                   titulo_en, 
                                   descricao, 
                                   descricao_en, 
                                   dt_cadastro)
        SELECT  dt_agenda,
                titulo,
                titulo_en,
                descricao,
                descricao_en,
                dt_cadastro
        FROM tb_agenda
        WHERE dt_agenda < NOW();

        DELETE FROM tb_agenda
         WHERE dt_agenda < NOW();

        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

What's this: after inserting into `tb_agenda`, it's supposed to search for data which `dt_agenda` (date) is lower than `NOW()`, add into `tb_realizacao` and then delete this old data from `tb_agenda`. The problem is that the delete query seems not to be executed, the data is normally added into the `tb_realizacao` but not deleted from `tb_agenda`.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `new` to access the record being inserted?  Also, your loop is doing nothing  . . . looping over all the records in the table seems curious.

Comment: I need to delete old data. For instance, if I schedule an event for 06/22/2016, in 06/23/2016, if I insert a new event, the event from 06/22/2016 is supposed to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

No need to set WHERE since NOW means that all of them will be removed. No need for WHILE since every trigger has FOR EACH ROW. You cannot delete from table where you insert so delete will be in the php script.

php script:

```
$pdo->query("DELETE FROM tb_agenda");
$pdo->query("INSERT ...");
```

trigger:
 Table: tb_agenda
 Time: BEFORE
 Event: DELETE

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tb_realizacao (dt_agenda,
                               titulo, 
                               titulo_en, 
                               descricao, 
                               descricao_en, 
                               dt_cadastro)
    VALUES  (OLD.dt_agenda,
            OLD.titulo,
            OLD.titulo_en,
            OLD.descricao,
            OLD.descricao_en,
            OLD.dt_cadastro);

END;
```